# Problemas al cargar storyboard xcode 9

Tags: swift3

Me ha surgido un problema con `xcode 9`.

Resulta que tengo un proyecto en `swift 3`, lo tengo en una mac y el `xcode` donde se creo fue como por el 6, pero en la misma mac se ha ido actualizando el `xcode` desde la tienda hasta llegar el 9, el problema es que ahora en una mac nueva el `xcode` se instala desde 0 , no se actualiza como usualmente pasaba pero en el `xcode` que se acaba de instalar el proyecto al querer visualizar el `storyboard` se alienta mucho y se traba, no me deja ver por ejemplo la vista de mitad y mitad (Vista y `Controller`), entonces al hacer eso pues tengo que forzar a detener `xcode`, lo curioso es que con otros proyectos que se empezaron mas nuevos no sucede esto y no tengo idea de qué configuración mover, las diferencias que veo es que en el `xcode` de la mac anterior aunque tiene el 9 el `sdk` aparece como 10.3 y en el nuevo solo me deja el 11, pero en realidad no se si sea eso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno ya se soluciono, lo que paso es que necesitaba actualizar un POD, de una librería que utilizo que se llama FSCalendar, esa librería tenia problemas al utilizarla en xcode 9 al parecer y por eso se trababa en el storyboard.

Saludos

Comment: el día de mañana marca esta respuesta como aceptada mediante el check verde.